# App Engine Full Text Search Document Indexing Fails on Unicode ½

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Documents with fields (TextField) containing the unicode character U+00BD (VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF) cannot be added to a full text search index.

I can create the document but attempting to add to an index with `search.Index(name = "test").put(d)` raises a search.Error exception withe the message `"Error: one or more put document operations failed: Failed to index"`

Has anyone else had problems indexing unicode strings? Any suggestions?

The example below fails for me. Change `c` to a different string (even non-ascii unicode string works.)

```
from google.appengine.api import search

c = u'½'  # This fails but c=u'©' works

doc = search.Document(
    doc_id   = "1",
    fields   =  [search.TextField(name = "field1", value = c)],
    language = 'en'
  )

search.Index(name = "test").put(doc)
```

Regards
Richard

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I'd suggest filing an issue in the tracker: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: This was indeed a bug, and should be fixed now.  Thanks for reporting it.